# Filter a list element starting with a letter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to sort out list elements that starts with 'N' into a new list.
Why won't this work?

```
const countries = ['Norway', 'Sweden',  'Denmark', 'New Zealand'];

function firstN(){
  for (let i=0;i<countries.length;i++){
    countries[i].startsWith("N")
    }
}

let startsWithN = countries.filter(firstN())
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of errors.  Post your real code please.  Line 2 doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @SanderB Are you expecting only elements beginning with `"N"` ar `startsWithN`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is roughly the same as @adeneo's answer, just a little terser:

```
const countries = ['Norway', 'Sweden',  'Denmark', 'New Zealand'];

const startsWithN = countries.filter((country) => country.startsWith("N"));

console.log(startsWithN);

// Output: [ 'Norway', 'New Zealand' ]
```

Comment: I wanted a solution without case sensitive. I end up with this, itemsList.filter((item)=> item.toLowerCase().startsWith(e.target.value.toLowerCase());

Answer (score 5):

You'd filter based on a condition, the named function returns `true`  or `false` based on that condition

```js
const countries = ['Norway', 'Sweden', 'Denmark', 'New Zealand'];

function firstN(item) {
  return item.toLowerCase().indexOf('n') === 0;
}

let startsWithN = countries.filter(firstN);

console.log(startsWithN)
```

Comment: OP is trying to sort the input array.

Comment: @guest271314 - Yes, I believe so, in the sense that *"sort out.. into a new list"* means a filter ?

Comment: No. OP is expecting all elements of input array to be included at resulting array, that is `countries`; with elements beginning with `"N"` at first indexes of array. Not certain if an option other than `.sort()` could be used due to `const`?

Comment: @guest271314 - That's neither what the question says, nor the OP's code is trying to do ?

Comment: _"I am trying to sort out list elements that starts with 'N' into a new list."_ From perspective here, "sort" does not mean "filter", but include all elements of existing array at new array, or using `.sort()`, same array. Though interpretation of Question, here, could be incorrect.

Comment: @guest271314 - I guess it's unclear then, I assumed the OP wanted a filter

Comment: If OP wants `.filter()` can use existing `javascript` without `.filter()`, will post an Answer fwiw. Have not been able to compose a `compare` function for `.sort()` to return elements with `"N"` as first character first.

Comment: Was able to put together a compare function for `.sort()` which sorts by first letter by adjusting an example at https://www.sitepoint.com/sophisticated-sorting-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

```
const freinds = ['Salman', 'Asad',  'Shahrukh', 'Aman'];
const startsS = freinds.filter((freind) => freind.startsWith("s"));
console.log(startsS);
```

Output:

> [ 'Salman', 'Shahrukh' ]

Comment: attach this code to any online code editor like jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Very straightforward:

```js
const countries = ['Norway', 'Sweden',  'Denmark', 'New Zealand'];

let startsWithN = countries.filter(function (country) {
  return country[0].toLowerCase() === 'n';
});

console.log(startsWithN)
```

Answer (score 1):

Still terser:

```js
const countries = ['Norway', 'Sweden',  'Denmark', 'New Zealand'];

const startsWithN = countries.filter(/./.test.bind(/^N/));

console.log(startsWithN);
```

This passes a function to `filter` that is a curried version of [`RexExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test): it has the context (`this`) set to `/^N/`, i.e. a regular expression that matches strings that start with a capital N. The result is similar to this:

```
const startsWithN = countries.filter(country => /^N/.test(country));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
countries.filter(s => s.toLowerCase().indexOf("n") == 0)
```

Comment: How would result result affect `countries`?

Comment: it won't effect it at all. This will return the desired list.

Answer (score 0):

If expected result is a new array containing only elements of `countries` which begin with `"N"`, you can adjust existing `javascript` to create an array within `firstN`, pass the input array to `firstN`, `.push()` elements that pass `if` condition within `for` loop to new array, `return` new array

```js
const countries = ['Norway', 'Sweden', 'Denmark', 'New Zealand'];

function firstN(arr, letter) {
  for (let i = 0, res = []; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].startsWith(letter)) res.push(arr[i])
  }
  return res
}

let startsWithN = firstN(countries, "N");

console.log(startsWithN);
```

To sort the original array in place, you can use `.sort()`.

```js
const countries = ['Norway', 'Sweden', 'Denmark', 'New Zealand'];

function sortByFirstLetter(letter) {
  return function(a, b) {
    let [firstLetterA, firstLetterB] = [a[0], b[0]];
    return firstLetterA === letter && firstLetterB !== letter ? -1 : 1
  }
}

countries.sort(sortByFirstLetter("N"));

console.log(countries);
```

Comment: Note, `compare` function was adapted from an example found at [Sophisticated Sorting in JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/sophisticated-sorting-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

```
const countries = ['Norway', 'Sweden',  'Denmark', 'New Zealand'];

const startsWithN = countries.filter((country) => country[0]==='N');

console.log(startsWithN);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

```
const countries = ['Norway', 'Sweden', 'Denmark', 'New Zealand']

let sortedCountries = countries.filter((byCountry)=>
    (byCountry).startsWith('N'))
    console.log(sortedCountries)
```

You can use the filter and the string method (startsWith) to filter through an array

Hope this helps someone